# vscode in the browser copy/paste error: "The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying out VS Code in the browser (similar to Jupyter Labs, it might be called "vscode-server"?) but I'm getting an error when I try to copy/paste anything:

> The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a VS Code session in the browser.
2. Open a text editor in a terminal.
3. Try to paste something.
4. A popup shows a [link to a Chromium page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) about trusted content in iframes.

**How can I enable copy/pasting in VS Code in the browser?**

Here is the version info from "Help->About" if that is useful:

```
Code - OSS
Version: 1.44.2
Commit: fd36a99a4c78669970ebc4eb05768293b657716f
Date: 2020-04-29T20:40:08.161Z (5 mos ago)
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is this issue: [Clipboard API doesn’t work on Codespaces (using Safari)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106997).

> "The request to write to the clipboard must be triggered during a user
> gesture. A call to clipboard.write or clipboard.writeText outside the
> scope of a user gesture(such as "click" or "touch" event handlers)
> will result in the immediate rejection of the promise returned by the
> API call."

- from https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/

Just fixed in PR: [Workaround Safari clipboard.writeText behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/139657).

Available for testing in the Insidrs Build, might land in Stable v1.64 early February, 2021.